# Calling a function after 'n' seconds doesn't work in some times

Tags: android

I created an application which is basically a call whitelister! I also implemented a feature that user can set a time in minutes for each added number, so that the call will be disconnected after the alloted 'n' minutes for that specif number. Everything happens in a service! Call whitelisting is working perfect that only numbers added to my app gets connected and all other will be  diconnected!
But the issue i am facing is with the disconnection after n minutes.
My code for that logic is below;

```
if (calltype.equals("INCOMING") || calltype.equals("OUTGOING")) {
        //Getting the alloted time in minutes from database fro the dialed number!
        int userTime = Integer.parseInt(whiteListDao.getLimit(number));
        //checking is number is greater that 0. if less than 0 call will disconnected instantly!
        if (userTime > 0) {
            final int milli = userTime * 1000;
            int tickTime = 1000;
            final String finalNumber = number;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                    updateMyDB(finalNumber);
                }
            }, milli);
        } else {
            disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

But this works if time is less than 5 minutes! But when added 10 minutes or higher this will not work in many cases! Why is that!! Please help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Use AlarmManager

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך.. Can you please post a sample code?

Comment: You can see about it at https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CountDownTimer for the same purpose, and this works perfectly for all Android versions.

```
 private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


        if(calltype.equals("INCOMING")||calltype.equals("OUTGOING"))

        {
            //Getting the alloted time in minutes from database fro the dialed number!
            int userTime = Integer.parseInt(whiteListDao.getLimit(number));
            //checking is number is greater that 0. if less than 0 call will disconnected instantly!
            if (userTime > 0) {
                final int milli = userTime * 1000;
                int tickTime = 1000;
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milli, tickTime) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // timer is running
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        // time is over
                        disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                        updateMyDB(finalNumber);
                    }
                }.start();
            } else {
                disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
            }
        }


@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (countDownTimer != null) {
           countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that!! But that has also the same issue!! :(

Comment: Are you sure? because I am also using the same in my app for 20 mins schedule and this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ohh.. it was working in my end!! But client always says that, when students call he/she is needed to disconnect rather than auto disconnect after 10 minutes!! Are you sure you run this in service! My app will not be in foreground

Comment: Yupp, i am using in service and app is in background

Comment: I think the service is stopping in some cases!

Comment: Can you please share how your service is getting started and how did you handle the unexpected destroying of service that can occur!